# How can I grab an HTML slider value as an integer for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, slider

I'm trying to obtain a value out of an HTML slider so I can dynamically use it as an integer in JavaScript.
The problem I'm having is I can't seem to use the value as a proper integer.
For example, if my slider value was 5 & if l tried to store it in a variable and add 10, it would output  as '510' instead.
Maybe I'm an idiot and missing something very fundamental or simple, but it always ends up as a string in the end.
I have tried parseInt() as well, but it doesn't seem to help.
I've set up a simple example of code below:

**JS**

```
    var sliderUnit = document.getElementById("slider"); 
    var outputUnit = document.getElementById("amtOutput");
    var a = 0;
    var b = 10;
    outputUnit.innerHTML = sliderUnit.value;
    sliderUnit.oninput = function(){
        outputUnit.innerHTML = this.value;
        console.log(sliderUnit.value);
        a = this.value;
        parseInt(a);
    }
   
    function test(){
        b += a;
        console.log("b: " + b + " | a: " + a);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="sliderContainer">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="15" value="7" id="slider">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="test()" />
    | Slider number: <span id="amtOutput"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your are calling the `parseInt(a)` but the returned Integer value is not being handled properly, you should do as this `a = parseInt(a);`

```js
var sliderUnit = document.getElementById("slider"); 
    var outputUnit = document.getElementById("amtOutput");
    var a = 0;
    var b = 10;
    outputUnit.innerHTML = sliderUnit.value;
    sliderUnit.oninput = function(){
        outputUnit.innerHTML = this.value;
        console.log(sliderUnit.value);
        a = this.value;
        a = parseInt(a); // Change this line
    }
   
    function test(){
        b += a;
        console.log("b: " + b + " | a: " + a);
    }
```

```html
<div class="sliderContainer">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="15" value="7" id="slider">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="test()" />
    | Slider number: <span id="amtOutput"></span>
</div>
```

If not the variable a will continue to be a string becouse it wasn't changed

Comment: l had a feeling l was making a dumb mistake, l should have figured l wasn't defining a again & using parseInt wrong lol
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string as int using `parseInt`.

**Working code:**

```js
var sliderUnit = document.getElementById("slider"); 
    var outputUnit = document.getElementById("amtOutput");
    var a = 0;
    var b = 10;
    outputUnit.innerHTML = sliderUnit.value;
    sliderUnit.oninput = function(){
        outputUnit.innerHTML = this.value;
        console.log(sliderUnit.value);
        a = this.value;
        parseInt(a);
    }
   
    function test(){
        b = parseInt(b) 
        a = parseInt(a);
        b += a;
        console.log("b: " + b + " | a: " + a);
    }
```

```html
<div class="sliderContainer">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="15" value="7" id="slider">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="test()" />
    | Slider number: <span id="amtOutput"></span>
</div>
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1cuLf724/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, l had parseInt in my function above, but l was using it incorrectly